# Convert decimal hours to 'hh:mm' format - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-conversion

This is more of a solution than question.

I've looked at many threads to find a good solution for converting decimal hours into 'hh:mm' format but only got bits and pieces here and there. So thought, I'd share my solution if it's useful for anyone.

Mods - please feel free to optimize/refine my function.

Answer (score 0):

```
--this will convert 45.50 to '45:30' or -45.50 to '-45:30'
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetTimeFromNumericValue](@numerichours numeric(24,6))
RETURNS varchar(6) --Only string takes negative
AS
BEGIN

Declare @returnvalue numeric(24,6) ;
Declare @left varchar(10);
Declare @right varchar(10);

If(@numerichours is NULL OR @numerichours = 0.0 )
Begin
     Return '';
End
Else if (@numerichours<0)
Begin
     set @numerichours = ABS(@numerichours)
     Return '-' + RIGHT('0'+Convert(varchar, FLOOR(@numerichours)),2) +':' +  RIGHT('0'+Convert(varchar,Convert(int,((@numerichours - FLOOR(@numerichours)) * 60))),2)
End
Else
Begin
     Return RIGHT('0'+Convert(varchar, FLOOR(@numerichours)),2) +':' +  RIGHT('0'+Convert(varchar,Convert(int,((@numerichours - FLOOR(@numerichours)) * 60))),2)
End

Return '';

End
```